# Could not build android project due to jcenter repository Bad gateway : 502 from server

Tags: android, jcenter

Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

Comment: this happening in general for jcenter. :( wget https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/vaadin/vaadin-sass-compiler/maven-metadata.xml
--2019-03-21 08:26:08--  https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/vaadin/vaadin-sass-compiler/maven-metadata.xml
Resolving jcenter.bintray.com (jcenter.bintray.com)... 52.34.114.104, 35.164.178.254
Connecting to jcenter.bintray.com (jcenter.bintray.com)|52.34.114.104|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 502 Bad Gateway

Comment: I confirm 502 Bad Gateway error with jcenter related compile.

Comment: Same is happening here. Is there any solution available? I have been searching for last 2,3 hours. Didn't found anything useful.

Comment: "Intermittent download issues in Bintray" See this https://status.bintray.com/

Comment: To fix it open android sdk manager and:
1.Uninstall android support repository 2.Install again android support repository 3.clean and rebuild project